# How to delete lines where the given part of the line is more than 100 chars?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I know I can delete lines that are longer than 100 chars with this:

```
sed '/^.\{100\}..*/d'
```

But I have the following example line:

```
<a href="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</a><br>
```

So I need to only delete the lines where "YYY":

```
">Y...Y...Y</a><br>
```

is longer than 100 chars. How can I do this?

I'm using OpenBSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -vE '">[^<>]{101,}</a><br>'
```

To remove lines that contain more than 100 non-<> characters between a `">` and a `</a><br>`.

Answer (score 1):

Same as above (if I understand right what you want to do, that is):

```
sed -e '/Y\{100\}/d'
```

This matches all lines containing 100 Y in a row, and deletes them.

Comment: this works too! but the upper "grep" one is more "general"